# SQL Server Integration Services throws "Error Starting Debugging" - Failed to start project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

Several of my colleagues and I are experiencing a problem: we are trying to use the Visual Studio Business Intelligence Designer (BIDS) to create and debug SQL Server Integration Services packages.  In nearly all cases, we encounter the error below.

We all have SQL Server 2008R2 Management Studio installed, which includes the Visual Studio 2008 BIDS IDE.  We all have Visual Studio 2010 installed as our primary development IDE / environment, and connect to a Team Foundation Server source control.

We do not have a source control plugin selected for the BIDS IDE.

We are all running Windows 7 with all the latest service packs and patches (as far as we know- these are customer-managed machines and the patch management details are opaque to us).

The one thing that is different - maybe - between the one system where the SSIS debugger DOES work and the several where it DOESN'T work is that- MAYBE- the operable system has not been used to edit SQL Server Reporting Service RDL files, where the rest have been.

In the Project Properties dialog, under the Debugging options:
We have tried setting the "runInOptimizedMode" option to False - no joy.
We have tried setting the "Run64BitRuntime" option to False- no joy.
We have tried setting the "InteractiveMode" option to "False" - no joy.

Here is the error text as reported by the BIDS interface.

Thanks for any insights you have!

---

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Failed to start project

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error starting debugging. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

---

Unable to start program 'C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\projects\DebugTest\DebugTest\Package.dtsx'.

Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80040038. (Microsoft Visual Studio Debugger)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: This smells like the Integration Services isn't installed. If you open a command prompt (Start->Run **cmd**) and then type `dtexec /?` what does it report? What if you typed `dtexec.exe /file "C:\Users\Keith Adams\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\projects\DebugTest\DebugTest\Package.dtsx"`

Comment: Hi-  Pretty sure it's installed.. DTEXEC answered the bell with the help info when I did dtexec /?, and when I entered the patch to the package itself I got a start time, DTEXEC return code )DTSER_SUCCESS), finish time, and elapsed time.

Comment: I did note that it was the 64 bit version  -- I'll try hunting that down and getting to only the 32 bit versions.

Comment: Excellent. I have seen that people will install BIDS/SSDT but that doesn't mean the IS Service is there (command line call verifies that). You will have both the 32 and 64 bit version of SSIS installed, it's just a matter of which entry comes first in your $PATH environment variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787007/how-to-execute-dtsx-packages-through-command-line/8790987#8790987

Comment: No joy.  I found DTEXEC in both the Program Files and Program Files(x86) paths; renaming the one in Program Files changed the signature to prove that the 32 bit version was now responding but no change in behavior when invoking the BIDS debugger.

Comment: On the premise that maybe there were other DLLs that were getting picked up and affecting the behavior of the debugger, I also rearranged the PATH environment variable to put all of the Program Files (x86) references related to SQL Server and Visual Studio ahead of the analogous 64-bit Program files items.  Still no joy... :(

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio as Administrator that works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).