# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created as SSSIS package in BIDS 2013 and deployed code on server with following configuration:

```
Window Server: 2012
SQL Server: 2014
```

SSIS is working fine. but when I change Server Configuration as below:

```
Window Server: 2008
SQL Server : 2012
```

I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Hi, is your server 2008 32/64 bit?

Comment: The windows server/SQL server and developed package should be same bit. Else change the run64bitruntime to 32 bit and try. Another option would be try to run your package in win server 2008 by using dtexec utility via command prompt by pointing managedDTS 32bit/64 bit. Check which one is working? definitely atleast one should work. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787007/how-to-execute-dtsx-packages-through-command-line

Comment: The Windows versions don't matter at all. However, backward compatibility is not a feature. You developed in against 2014, you must deploy to 2014. If you developed against 2012, then you could go forward to 2014 without redoing it but as it stands, no dice

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a different context.  I solved mine by installing MS SQL Server 2014 Management Studio (SSMS 2014), which can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46697

You can install the entire SSMS 2014 bundle, or select specific modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with BimlStudio.
You should try adding Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll file in Bids folder located in program files.