# Running SSIS job using Windows task scheduler

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, scheduler

I am new to the world of ETL. I recently started using SSIS and I have come across couple of questions on this.

```
1.Can we run a SSIS Package using windows task scheduler?
2. If the above answer is yes,I don't have the SSMS installed on my machine. Can a SSIS package run in the absence of SSMS?(I do have
Visual studio and SQL server data tools installed)
3. Can a SSIS Package run in the absence of Visual studio and SQL Server Data Tools.Say for example, I create a SSIS package and then
remove Visual studio and SQL server data tools from my machine. Will
the Task scheduler still be able to run the SSIS package?
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why the Windows Task Scheduler and not use the Built in Sql Server Agent?

Comment: I don't have the SQL server Management studio to leverage the SQL server agent.

Comment: why not? it's free... Anyway.. You can  run a cmd with Windows task scheduler, you can run a package with the cmd DTEXEC.

Comment: Can i get the management studio alone from the Microsoft's site?. Could you please give more info on your second point?

Comment: Just Google SSMS Download. Here is a good post on SO about DTEXEC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787007/how-to-execute-dtsx-packages-through-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run SSIS job from command prompt  through DTEXEC utility 
check this query

dtexec /f  
/set \package.variables[Variable]; value

Example:-   dtexec /f E:\test_package\test_package\Package.dtsx
/set \package.variables[id];1

Reference:- [Methods to execute SSIS Package](http://microsoft-sql-ssis.blogspot.in/2015/09/running-ssis-package-from-command.html)