# How to run SSIS package without opening IDE (Visual Studio)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, powershell, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am using Powershell script to run the SSIS package.
Below is my code:-

```
runas /user:ABC /savecred "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe D:\SSIS.sln /run"
```

However, the code above runs the SSIS package by opening Visual Studio.
How do I make the SSIS package runs without opening the Visual Studio ?

Comment: See answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8790987/847990

Comment: I use SQL Agent to run the task. Is SQL Server Management Studio an option?

Comment: You mean SQL Server Agent executes the Powershell script which eventually executes the SSIS package ? It wouldn't open the Visual Studio this way ? FYI, I do not want to put the SSIS package directly under SQL Server Agent. It must go through the Powershell script. @Rubix_Revenge

Comment: I believe it can if you define a job step in Agent. I have not written a job step myself that runs a powershell command, but I know it can be done. You can then run the job on a schedule or manually tell the job to run.